# Can be shown just a single photo in MWPhotoBrowser

Tags: ios, ios7, mwphotobrowser

I am having a look at the `MWPhotoBrowser` library on **GitHub**, and I see that I can use it as a Photo Browser with multiple pictures on it.

Now I don't want to do this, but I want just to click on a photo from my `viewController` push to `MWPhotoBrowser` and just show it on fullscreen, so I can use functions that `MWPhotoBrowser` has (zooming, etc). See the photo below:

[image]

If there is no way to do this without showing browser in `MWPhotoBrowser`, then can you suggest me another library that I could use to achieve this thing?